# Will a Registry Class in PHP work like this?

Tags: php, registry

If I create a registry object to store other objects and settings in like this...

```
$registry = Registry::getInstance();
```

And then create 2 other objects and pass the Registry object into them like this below...

```
$core = new core($registry);
$database = Database::getInstance($registry);
```

and then later in the script I add some objects to the Registry object...

```
// Store some Objects into our Registry object using a Registry Pattern
$registry->storeObject("database", $database);
$registry->storeObject("session", $session);
$registry->storeObject("cache", $cache);
$registry->storeObject("user", $user);
```

Will methods in the core and database objects that were  created at the top, still have access to all the objects that I store into the registry even though the other objets were stored into the registry AFTER the core and database Objects were created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes they will, objects are passed by reference (in php >= 5) so, each variable will refer to the same underlying object.

in old php, you would need to pass by ref:

```
$obj->registry =& $registry;

function f(& $registry) { // $registry is a reference }
```

the key in php <5 is the ampersand syntax when assigning and in function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

If its the same instance of the object, than yes - otherwise they'll have to use shared memory to pass the objects around or no, you won't have access to them.

However, I'd imagine your registry is a singleton right? So yes.

edit: maybe Im not understanding your question ....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they'll have access to these object, but IMO Registry isn't the best solution here - Context would be much better because it allows you to model each property. It also gives you 100% sure that when you call `$registry->get('user')` some `User` object will be returned.

Context is pretty similar to Registry:

```
class Context {
    protected $database;
    protected $user;
    protected $logger;

    public function setDatabse(PDO $database) {
       $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function getDatabase() {
       return $this->database;
    }

    public function setLogger(Logger $logger) {
       if ($logger instanceof MySpecificLogger) {
          // do sth
       }

       $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    // rest of setters/getters
}
```

And when you use it later:

```
$db = $contextObject->getDatabase();
```

When you use Registry you don't have 100% sure that $db is then an object of `PDO` (in this example) what might causes some problems in some situations.

Comment: Am I wrong or is this very similar to a registry?  Wouldn't I still have to pass this Context object into all my other objects?  Just asking I am new to this

Comment: Yes, you'll still have to pass Context instance to other objects. The main difference between Context and Registry is visible in methods `setDatabase` and `setLogger`. When you use Registry you cannot do anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

No, not by default. Parameters are passed by value in PHP in almost every case. What you want is called "passing by reference", which you can read more about [in the manual](http://se.php.net/references).

Comment: Objects in PHP since 5th version are passed by reference by default.

Comment: If this class implements the singleton pattern, the classes share the same instance